# Difference in spin angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, vectors

In chemistry, I learnt that the spin angular moment of a single unpaired electron in an atom can be calculated by
$\frac{\sqrt{3} h} {4\pi}$,
but while studying radioactivity, I studied that the spin angular momentum of a free electron is
$\frac{h}{4\pi}$.

Please explain, what causes the difference in spin angular momentum, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In chemistry, I learnt that the spin angular moment of a single unpaired electron in an atom can be calculated by
> $\frac{\sqrt{3} h} {4\pi}$,

This value $\frac{\sqrt{3} h} {4\pi}$ is the value of the positive square root of the eigenvalues of the $S^2$ operator for an electron (or other spin 1/2 particle), where
$$
S^2 = S_x^2 + S_y^2 + S_z^2\;,
$$
which is the operator for the squared spin angular momentum in general, and for an electron in particular.

> but while studying radioactivity, I studied that the spin angular momentum of a free electron is
> $\frac{h}{4\pi}$.

This value $\frac{h}{4\pi}$ is the magnitude of the eigenvalues of the $S_z$ operator for an electron (or other spin 1/2 particle), where $S_z$ can be written in an eigen-basis as:
$$
S_z = \frac{h}{4\pi}\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{matrix}\right)
$$

> Please explain, what causes the difference in spin angular momentum, and why?

The difference is due to the fact that $\frac{\sqrt{3} h} {4\pi}$ is the square root of the eigenvalue of the $S^2$ operator, whereas $\frac{h}{4\pi}$ is an eigenvalue of the $S_z$ operator (or $S_x$ or $S_y$). In other words, the former is associated with the magnitude of a vector and the latter is associated with the component value.

In the same eigenbasis we can write the $S_y$ and $S_x$ operators as:
$$
S_x = \frac{h}{4\pi}\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
S_y = \frac{h}{4\pi}\left(\begin{matrix}0 & -i \\ i & 0\end{matrix}\right)\;.
$$

And we can write the squares in this basis as:
$$
S_x^2 = S_y^2 = S_z^2 = \left(\frac{h}{4\pi}\right)^2\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and therefore:
$$
S^2 = 3\left(\frac{h}{4\pi}\right)^2\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)
$$

And, therefore the positive square root of (either) eigenvalue of the $S^2$ matrix is:
$$
\sqrt{3}\frac{h}{4\pi}
$$

---

Note, in general, for a spin $s$ particle the eigenvalues of the $S^2$ operator are $s(s+1)\frac{h}{2\pi}$. Spin is a quantum mechanical phenomenon and the value of the eigenvalue of the quantum $S^2$ operator has little to do with our intuition about the length of a classical vector. The fact that eigenvalues of $S^2$ are $3s^2$ for an electron is not true in general.

Answer (score 2):

The spin $\vec{S}$ is a vector. This means it has 3 cartesian components ($S_x,S_y,S_z$).
And the magnitude of the spin vector is $S=|\vec{S}|=\sqrt{S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2}$.

Your confusion is caused by the fact that literature often doesn't
clearly say whether it means the size of these components ($S_x,S_y,S_z$)
or the magnitude of the vector ($S$).

The [electron is known to have spin quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_quantum_number#Electron_spin) $s=\frac 12$.
This is short-hand for saying
(and here I use the so-called [reduced Planck constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant#Reduced_Planck_constant_%E2%84%8F) $\hbar$
which is just a convenient abbreviation for $\frac{h}{2\pi}$):

1. The spin components $S_x$, $S_y$, $S_z$ when measured
   yield a result of either $+\frac{1}{2}\hbar$ or
   $-\frac{1}{2}\hbar$ (and
   never a value in between).
2. The magnitude of the spin vector is $S=\sqrt{s(s+1)}\hbar$.
   For $s=\frac{1}{2}$ this means $S=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\hbar$.

Comment: I think this argument that "(2) follows from (1) by means of [considering the length of a vector with all arguments equal to the $S_z$ eigenvalue]" is incorrect. After considering it for a moment, it seems like an argument that "64 divided by 16 is 4, just cancel the sixes." In other words, you arrived at the right answer, but the reasoning is faulty. The eigenvalue of $S^2 = S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2$ is $s(s+1)$. The positive eigenvalues of $S_z$, $S_x$, and $S_y$ are $s$. The only way your argument works is when $\sqrt{s(s+1)}=\sqrt{3}s$, which is only true when $s=0$ or $s=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: For example, if $s=1$, your argument would suggest that $S=\sqrt{3}$, but, in fact $S=\sqrt{s(s+1)} = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: (In my comments I set $\hbar=1$.)

Comment: That's not how you get the Eigenvalue for $S^2$, this answer is flat out wrong.

Comment: @AfterShave i know this simple reasoning doesn't work for $s>\frac 12$. But for $s=\frac 12$ it is legit because $S_x$ never takes values *between* $\pm \frac 12$.

Comment: You arrived at the right answer by accident, I would delete this to avoid confusing people. The different components of $\mathbf{S}$ are not compatible so you can't just add their eigenvalues together.

Comment: @AfterShave I removed this part.