# Superposition and Electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

I was watching the following video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkAAbXPEAtU). It discusses the electron spin quantum number $m_s$. It then discusses that an electron may be classified as having spin up or spin down. From what I understand, an electron that has down spin never will have spin up. To detect whether or not an electron has up or down spin, you shoot it through a [quantum magnet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDxUaBYINeQ) and if it goes towards the south pole of the magnet it has spin up. In simple terms, how can it be that an electron is in a state of superposition where we don't know whether the electron is spin up or down? I feel like I am missing something here theoretically.

Comment: "*From what I understand, an electron that has down spin never will have spin up*" From *what* you understand that?

Comment: That's what I have come across watching videos. Is that incorrect?

Comment: The electron "spin" is the electron's own angular momentum, its magnitude is always the same, but its orientation can be changed.

Comment: So, if an electron is spin up, does it have to remain spin up? So, if you orient the quantum magnet on its side, it will go sideways but still to the south poll just like if you did it vertically.

Comment: I do not know what a "quantum magnet" is but with spin comes magnetic dipole moment and that can interact with an external magnetic field changing the dipole's and its associated spin's orientation. See, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/782694/difference-in-spin-angular-momentum

Comment: We are talking about the same thing/experiment. Is it true if an electron goes to the north pole that if you use the same electron again, that it will go to the north pole again?

Comment: if the 2nd field has the same direction then why would the spin orientation change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In quantum mechanics, we solve the Schrodinger Equation to find a **basis** for our states. The states are what the system occupies. It is a result of linear algebra that a state can be written as a sum (**linear combination**) of the basis states.

One classic example in quantum mechanics is the two state system where our basis is the states $\vert \uparrow \rangle$ and $\vert \downarrow \rangle$. The system exists in a sum of these (**superposition**). Call the state $\vert \psi \rangle = \alpha \vert \uparrow \rangle + \beta \vert \downarrow \rangle$. Then, what happens when we make a measurement is that the state collapses onto one of these states. We see the system in a state of spin up with $\vert \alpha \vert ^2$ probability, and we see it in the down state with $\vert \beta \vert ^2$ probability. If we put it through your so-called "quantum magnet" and **measure** it after, we will measure spin up or down, but the state was not in either prior to the measurement. It was in a linear combination (sum) of states.

I recommend as silly goose said to read Sakurai section 1 to clarify these concepts if you are interested. The Stern-Gerlach section clarifies everything you are asking.

**Edit:**
You seem to be thinking that because we see an outcome, that means the system was in the observed state always. That is a false assumption. When we measure a system, we extract information about it. Consider a very crude example where a basket has 5 blue balls and 5 red balls. If you pull one ball out and it is blue, this tells you information about the system. There is no reason to assume this tells you the state of the system. All these measurements do is extract some information. Instead of thinking "how does quantum mechanics explain this classical result?", you should be asking yourself "how do I get this classical result from the quantum phenomenon?".

Comment: I appreciate your help with this. I understand from a mathematical perspective that there are certain models for this. From a non-mathematical perspective, I still don't understand how you can say the state of the electron was not declared to have spin-up or spin-down prior to the measurement. Electron A had spin-down because it was deflected downward in the quantum magnet. Electron A continues to spin down if the orientation of the magnet is not changed. Why can we not say that electron A did not spin down before putting it through the machine? I'm looking for a non-mathematical answer

Comment: I made another edit. Does this clarify anything? Again, you should read Sakurai -- it explains exactly your question. @WilliamGarske

Answer (score 0):

Recall that you measure the spin of an electron with respect to some direction. If you set up some xyz axes and find the electron in the $\lvert +z \rangle$ state, then it is an early example to show that
$$\lvert +z \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert +x \rangle + \lvert -x \rangle).$$

Hence, a spin-1/2 particle measured to be in the spin-z state is equivalently in a superposition of spin-x states.

Comment: So, the idea of superposition is not really that it is flipping between up and down but rather a sum? Can you explain this more simply? I do not know what the $|+z\rangle$ means. I understand pure math and am not a physicist.

Comment: When a system is in a superposition of states, that means you cannot say that the system is occupying any one of those states. Hence, your notion of “flipping between up and down” is incorrect as it presumes the system is occupying one of its states at any given time. @WilliamGarske

Comment: I recommend looking at an introductory quantum mechanics text like J.J. Sakurai or Townsend. @WilliamGarske

Comment: So, my question is how can you say that it is not occupying any one of those states spin up or spin down? For example, the electron is clearly spin down before you put it through the magnet and showed it was indeed spin down. That's the part I am not understanding.

Comment: @WilliamGarske https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition